# How to make this "svngrep" alias work on ".bash_aliases"?

Tags: scripts, alias

I added to following line to the "~/.bash_aliases" file:

```
alias svngrep='grep -R $1 ./* --exclude-dir ".svn"'
```

but it's not working.

It outputs (in my translation to English):

```
svngrep test
grep: test: File or directory not found
```

But with the full "grep" line it works just fine.

Any idea what's wrong with my alias?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$1` does not work in an alias. You need to define a function for that, for example in your .bashrc file.

```
function svngrep { grep -R --exclude-dir=".svn" "$@" . ; }
```

This should do the trick! However, make sure that your old alias is not around before trying it out from the command line:

```
unalias svngrep
function svngrep { grep -R --exclude-dir=".svn" "$@" . ; }
svngrep "teststring"
```

Quoting [bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Aliases):

> There  is  no  mechanism  for  using  arguments  in the replacement text.  If arguments are needed, a shell function should be used (...) For almost every purpose, **aliases are superseded by shell functions**.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a bash function (you may use it though, matter of taste), just remove the `$1 ./*` from your example and call it this way:

```
alias svngrep='grep -R --exclude-dir ".svn"'
svngrep phrase .
```

or here's an example I've been using for months:

```
alias rg='rgrep --exclude-dir=.svn --exclude=*.pyc'
rg phrase .
```

Of course, you can substitute `.` with any directory. I'd say using aliases is more intuitive, alias is an alias, function can do anything.

Comment: In principle yes, but there is no reason to prefer alias over function. Functions are not longer (instead of ="" you need to type { ;}), but are more flexible and can take arguments.